# Checkbox works but radio button not working in AnguarJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and filter option, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="{{cat}}" ng-model="ctrl.filter[cat]" id='{{$index}}' class='chk-btn styled-checkbox' ng-click="removeAnother();"/>
```

This works very good. When I select an item, its getting right values. But I don't need multiple select so I wanna convert checkboxes to radio buttons.

If I use radio button, our functions not working. Please check the **[demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/tgp33x0a/)**

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.
  module('myApp', []).
  controller('WineCtrl', WineCtrl);

  // Functions - Definitions
  function WineCtrl() {
    // Variables - Private
    var self = this;

    // Variables - Public
    self.filter = {};
    self.wines = [{
        name: 'Wine A',
        category: 'red'
      },
      {
        name: 'Wine B',
        category: 'red'
      },
      {
        name: 'Wine C',
        category: 'white'
      },
      {
        name: 'Wine D',
        category: 'red'
      },
      {
        name: 'Wine E',
        category: 'red'
      },
      {
        name: 'Wine F',
        category: 'white'
      },
      {
        name: 'Wine G',
        category: 'champagne'
      },
      {
        name: 'Wine H',
        category: 'champagne'
      }
    ];

    // Functions - Public
    self.filterByCategory = filterByCategory;
    self.getCategories = getCategories;

    // Functions - Definitions
    function filterByCategory(wine) {
      return (self.filter[wine.category] || noFilter(self.filter)) ? 'show' : 'hide';
    }

    function getCategories() {
      return (self.wines || []).
      map(function(wine) {
        return wine.category;
      }).
      filter(function(wine, idx, arr) {
        return arr.indexOf(wine) === idx;
      });
    }

    function noFilter(filterObj) {
      return Object.
      keys(filterObj).
      every(function(key) {
        return !filterObj[key];
      });
    }
  }

}());
```

```css
.hide {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="WineCtrl as ctrl">
  <b>Category:</b>
  <div ng-repeat="category in ctrl.getCategories()">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.filter[category]" />
      {{ category }}
    </label>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div ng-repeat="wine in ctrl.wines">
    <div class="{{ctrl.filterByCategory(wine)}}">
      {{ wine.name }} <i>({{ wine.category }})</i>
    </div>

  </div>
  <hr />
  <b>Number of results: {{ filteredWines.length }}</b>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried setting the default checked = false? <input type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.filter[category]" checked = "false"/>

Comment: I tried checked false but its not working. You can see the demo.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add `ng-value="true"` so that the radio button will reflect the model value:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.filter[category]" ng-value="true" />
```

Then some directives to handle toggling:

```
<input ng-click="filter = !filter" ng-value="!filter" ng-checked="filter" type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.filter[category]" />
```

[new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tgp33x0a/4/)

Comment: I added ng-value but its not working. You can test the demo.

Comment: @J.Doe I tested the demo.  You will need other logic to handle the toggling of the radio buttons which I'll add above.

Comment: Yeah I was messing with it. You will use the filter to uncheck the other boxes. Nice Alex, beat me to it. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D